# Is there a way to use VueI18n library without having hard coded json/js files for each language?

Tags: vue.js, translate

I would like to be able to get data from our database that is output as English and be able to convert to another language using a drop down on the client.

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Do you expect Vuel18n library to make a translations for you?

Comment: I would expect that if I am including a library for translation it would translate to any language.... or do I have the wrong impression?  Something like google translate for Vue (which is what I though VueI18n would do)

Comment: Just imagine how big that library would be... 

Answer (score 1):

You can load language asynchrously and use `i18n.setLocaleMessage(lang, languageData)` to set language translations data.

```
const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'en', // set locale
  fallbackLocale: 'en',
})
function setI18nLanguage (lang) {
  i18n.locale = lang
  return lang
}

export function loadLanguageAsync(lang) {
  return axios.get('/your-api/' + lang).then(response => {
    const languageData = response.data
    i18n.setLocaleMessage(lang, languageData)
    return setI18nLanguage(lang)
  })
}
```

You can read [official document here](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/lazy-loading.html)

Comment: This would allow me to get different languages from DB, but what I want to do is get data from DB in English and have VueI18n translate the English words to respective locale selected from drop down. added +1 thanks.